# Python for the absolute beginner, Chapter 7 challenge 2

Tags: python, pickle

I've been going through the exercises in this book and I've hit a bit of a road block. The challenge is to:

"Improve the Trivia Challenge game so that it maintains a high-scores list in a file. The program should record the player's name and score. Store the high scores using a pickled object."

I've managed to save scores to a list and then append this list to a dat file. However, when I try to view the scores/read the file it only seems to show the first score entered. I took a look at the bat file and it seems to be dumping the list correctly, so I'm wondering if I'm messing up the retrieval part?

Thanks for reading

Here's the code (BEFORE):

```
def high_score():
    """Records a player's score"""
    high_scores = []

    #add a score
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    player_score = int(input("What is your score? "))
    entry = (name, player_score)
    high_scores.append(entry)
    high_scores.sort(reverse=True)
    high_scores = high_scores[:5]       # keep only top five

    # Open a new file to store the pickled list
    f = open("pickles1.dat", "ab")
    pickle.dump(high_scores, f)
    f.close()

    choice = None
    while choice !="0":
        print(
            """
            0 - Quit
            1 - Show high scores
            """
            )
        choice = input("choice: ")
        print()

        # exit
        if choice == "0":
            print("Goodbye")

        # show a score
        if choice == "1":
            f = open("pickles1.dat", "rb")
            show_scores = pickle.load(f)
            print(show_scores)
            f.close()

    input("\n\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Solution(AFTER):

```
def high_score():
"""Records a player's score"""

# no previous high score file
try:
    with open("pickles1.dat", "rb") as f:
        high_scores = pickle.load(f)
except EOFError:
    high_scores = []

#add a score // Do current stuff for adding a new score...
name = input("What is your name? ")
player_score = int(input("What is your score? "))
entry = (name, player_score)
high_scores.append(entry)
high_scores.sort(reverse=True)
high_scores = high_scores[:5]       # keep only top five

# dump scores
with open("pickles1.dat", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(high_scores, f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. @TokenMacGuy has identified one, which is that you're appending your results onto the end of the output file, rather than overwriting the previous values.

There is a more fundamental issue though. When you run the `highscores` function, you are always starting with an empty high score list. You then add a single score to it, and write it out. With this structure, you will never have more than one score being written at a time (and so even if you get it to read back what you've written properly, it will only get a 1-element list).

What you need to do is add some code to load the high score list from your file at the start of the function, before you add the new value. You need to put in a special case for when there is no previous high score file, but that's not too dificult with a `try`/`except` block. Here's some abbreviated code:

```
def high_score():
    try:
        with open("pickles1.dat", "rb") as f:
            high_scores = pickle.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        high_scores = []

    # do current stuff for adding a new score, sorting and slicing

    with open("pickles1.dat", "wb") as f: # "wb" mode overwrites the previous file
        pickle.dump(high_scores, f)

    # do other stuff, like displaying high_scores
```

A benefit to this approach is that you don't need to reread the file later if the user asks for it, since the `high_scores` list will be up to date already.

Comment: I keep getting an EOFError... "line 87, in high_score
    high_scores = pickle.load(f)
EOFError
" I'm not sure what is an acceptable way to show how I've implemented your code, can I possibly put it in pastebin and link it in the comments? Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Solved it! I replace the FileNotFoundError with and EOF error and removed the pickle.latest attribute, I'm using python 2.7 (according to this book) I think that's what kicked up the fuss. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open("pickles1.dat", "ab")
#                         ^
```

You have opened the file in "append" mode.  That's fine, but it's probably not doing what you want.  each time you try to save data to such a file, it is tacked on the end.  You'd have to read every single item you ever wrote to get to the most recently written.  instead, open the file in write mode.  This way, its contents will be replaced every time:

```
f = open("pickles1.dat", "wb")
```

alternatively, you can use appending, but you'll have to call `pickle.load()` repeatedly to see all of the written values.  Here's pseudocode, first for the former, with `"w"`

```
scores = pickle.load(open('scores.dat', 'rb'))
scores.append(123)
pickle.dump(scores, open('scores.dat', 'wb'))
```

and the latter:

```
pickle.dump(123, open('scores.dat', 'ab'))
scores = []
with open('scores.dat', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            scores.append(pickle.load(f))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

I hope you can see why I think the former (overwriting) is nicer; it's much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think my first post was entirely clear (sorry about that!). I used append mode because I wanted to save the all of the scores and then display only the top five. Initially, I opened the file in write mode, but that obviously meant I was only ever retaining one score at any given time. I'm basically trying to achieve: store all scores, display top 5. Hope this clarifies my question :).

Comment: From looking at those two examples I can definitely see how overwriting is the simpler solution. It seems you and Blckknght were coming from the same angle (if I've understood this correctly, haha). Onto the next chapter, thanks again!